# List users' Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure, openid-connect, azure-resource-manager, azure-ad-graph-api

My application uses Azure AD and OpenID Connect to sign-in users (see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect).

I want to be able to list users' Azure subscriptions when they've signed-in. I cannot figure what I need to do after a user has successfully signed-in and they've been redirected back to my app, i.e. how/where I get a hold of the necessary access token or credentials, and, to be honest, which is the correct API to call with said token/credentials. Can this be done? Is an entirely different approach necessary?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the notification events (raised as part of the sign-in flow) receives an authorization code. With the code, I was able to acquire an access token (using `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`) and, with that, I was able retrieve the subscriptions using this API `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions`. Note: ensure your AD application delegates permissions to the Service Management API.

Answer (score 1):

Look through the code in the example for an instance of `AuthenticationResult`. The access token can be accessed at `AuthenticationResult.AccessToken` and you can decide what you want to do based off that.